# Jenkins build from git repository in Dropbox

Tags: linux, git, jenkins

I have a main Git bare repository in my Dropbox folder and I'm using a headless Debian server which runs Jenkins to build my projects.

Until now I've been using this approach to build my projects: I created a bare git repository on my headless server and configured the Jenkins job to pull the sources from this repository with the following URL: `/var/cache/git/project`. So when I want Jenkins to build my changes, I have to push them to this repository. This works fine, but it's not very convenient because I have to manually push to two repositories (Dropbox and Debian) and also when I want to add a new project, I need to create a new repository on the Debian server.

So I decided to configure the Jenkins jobs to pull directly from the Dropbox repositories. I've set up Dropbox on my Debian server at `/home/jardo/Dropbox`.

But when I try to configure the Jenkins job to pull drom URL `/home/jardo/Dropbox/git/project.git`, I get the following error:

**Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h /home/jardo/Dropbox/git/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '/home/jardo/Dropbox/git/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

How come Jenkins is able to clone from `/var/cache/git/project`, but not from my Dropbox folder? Dropbox is completely synced and the repository content looks ok. I've set permissions on the whole repository recursively to 777 and that didn't help.

Here is the output of ls -l on my Dropbox repository:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jardo jardo  104 Dec 15 21:10 config
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jardo jardo   73 Dec 15 21:10 description
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jardo jardo   23 Dec 15 21:10 HEAD
drwxrwxrwx   2 jardo jardo 4096 Dec 24 13:16 hooks
drwxrwxrwx   2 jardo jardo 4096 Dec 24 13:01 info
drwxrwxrwx 150 jardo jardo 4096 Dec 24 13:01 objects
drwxrwxrwx   4 jardo jardo 4096 Dec 24 12:59 refs
```

Comment: I've done that only to make sure that this is not an issue with file permissions.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by showing the output of ls -l

Comment: @skrieder there you go, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that user Jenkins could not access the GIT repository, which was owned by user Jardo, even when I tried to set its permissions recursively to 777. The solution was to setup Dropbox also for user Jenkins.

Comment: Can you clarify how did you do that? Becoz now I have more or less same issue.